# Rails 3 "This webpage is not available" error

Tags: windows, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

It worked the last time I used, now I try and I got this error:
This webpage is not available
The webpage at http://0.0.0.0:7070/ might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.
Error 108 (net::ERR_ADDRESS_INVALID): Unknown error

This is in google chrome.
In other browsers there are not any specific information.

The routes file has only:

```
   get "main/index"
   root :to => "main#index"
```

Main controller:

```
   class MainController < ApplicationController
     def index

     end
   end
```

Index view:

```
   < h1 >Hey!< / h1>
   < p>Hey< /p>
```

Hosts file in windows have nothing special about the 0.0.0.0 url
I use mysql 6 on another port.
I dont really know what the problem is.

How I invoke the server:

```
   $ rails server -p 7070
   => Booting WEBrick
   => Rails 3.0.9 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:7070
   => Call with -d to detach
   => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
   [2011-07-26 11:39:20] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
   [2011-07-26 11:39:20] INFO  ruby 1.8.7 (2011-06-30) [i386-mingw32]
   [2011-07-26 11:39:20] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=3204 port=7070
```

Thanks

OK NOW IT WORKS! LOCALHOST:7070! WHAT IS HAPPENING? :OOOO

Comment: are you sure you're accessing the right port 7070?? and if yes then you may try this in your route: `resources :main` instead of get 'main/index" !! there are nothing to deal with hosts file actually cause Rails follows MVC architecture!!

Comment: Yes I run this "rails server -p 7070" and I access the "http://0.0.0.0:7070" url so it's right! No luck with changing the route to resources... And sometimes the windows hosts files may "block/alias" some urls, and what matters if Rails is MVC or not?

Comment: Are you sure you can access "0.0.0.0"? Shouldn't it be "127.0.0.1"?

Comment: even if I changed the ip by passing the "-p 127.0.0.1" it doesnt work

Comment: @Totty -p is an option for port so what ever you specify after -p will be treated as a port number !!

Comment: anyway the problem is solved. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just tried localhost:7070 and it works!
I still don't understand why but it's ok; 
the window's hosts file is untouched

Answer (score 1):

actually you have started your `localhost` server at port `7070` that's why it is only accessible with `localhost:7070` and not with just `localhost`. If you want to access your `localhost:7070` in numeric/ ip form then you should hit `127.0.0.1:7070` instead of `0.0.0.0`

Answer (score 1):

0.0.0.0 is the ip address that Webrick is binding to.  It means 'listen on all interfaces'.  In other words, you can connect to this application from the internal address (localhost or 127.0.0.1) as well as the external address on the network (192.168.1.x or 10.0.10.x or a domain name that resolves to an address this machine has on the network).  The server doesn't care where the request comes from.

If, however, you started rails server with the '-b' or '--binding' option and told the server to bind to 127.0.0.1, the server would not respond to requests to the external interface.  You could still use 127.0.0.1 or localhost but you could not connect to this server using it's external ip address locally or from another machine.

Going to http://0.0.0.0:3000 works on my Linux system and probably on a mac as well, but my guess is that http://0.0.0.0 isn't supported on Windows.

Just use localhost if you're on the box or the ip address of the box if your accessing it from another machine.  That is what I do, even when I'm running a machine that understands http://0.0.0.0.